# Use DirectShow to capture to an AVI from a non DirectShow source

Tags: c++, directshow

This may be a dumb question but I'm having a hard time conceptualizing what I need to do here...In the past I've used DirectShow to connect to a camera and capture an AVI using a source filter, AVI mux, compression filter, run the graph, etc...piece of cake. 
In this particular case I am getting notified when my non DirectShow camera driver has a buffer ready. I get notification and then I go and grab the BYTE* and render it using GDI. I now also need to create an AVI with these buffers.
Conceptually it makes sense for me to use something like vfw and write to an AVI stream every time I receive a buffer, of course vfw is old technology and I was also having some problems getting that to work (as I posted in a different forum).
How can I push these buffers into a DirectShow AVI Mux and write to a file? Do I have to create my own source filter to receive these buffers, then add my source filter and avi mux to a filter graph? 
Thanks for any tips

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have `BYTE*` with video frame data. It is very close to what you supposed. Your choices are to either use VFW [`AVIFileOpen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd756800%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and friends to write into `AVI` file, or inject data into DirectShow pipeline. To do the latter, you typically make your [PushSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd377481%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)-like filter and push video frames from there (through AVI Mux to File Writer).

Comment: Thanks Roman. I will look into creating  PushSource filter. Though I think I prefer using VFW, it seems like less work. I tried but was having problems with VFW,described here [Problems creating AVI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9106347/avi-created-with-avistreamwrite-has-incorrect-length-and-playback-speed). I'll keep plugging away. Thanks!

Comment: If your video is already compressed, then to write into AVI file you would be better off with `Video for Windows` (after all you don't need to even touch filters). If you yet need to compress (and yet to choose suitable compressor) and/or merge with audio, then perhaps `DirectShow` would be a better choice.

Comment: Yes I agree with you, I was looking into compressing the video in vfw and it seems like it would just make sense to use DirectShow if I need to compress. I'm going to work on both methodologies to get them working properly. If you have any thoughts on my VFW issue mentioned in my previous post I would appreciate it. Otherwise thanks very much for your help.